# Return amount of X in a string

Tags: javascript, strings

### I wrote code that returns how many of X is inside a string.

The script works fine, but i was wondering if there could be any changes to improve it.

```js
function getAmountOf(letter, string) {
    let count = 0;
    let amount = 0;
    function countAmount() {
        count += 1;
        let val = string[string.length - count];
        if ( val === letter ) {
            amount += 1;
        };
        if ( count == string.length ) {
            if ( amount == 1 ) {
                return `There's ${amount} ${letter} in ${string}`;
            } else {
                return `There's ${amount} ${letter}'s in ${string}`;
            };
        };
        return countAmount(string);
    };
    return countAmount(string);
};
console.log(getAmountOf('a', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several adjustments I'd recommend making:

**Consider using clearer variable names.**
This will help others more quickly understand your code.

- `count` and `amount` are similar enough to be confusing; `count` is being used to keep track of the index, so naming it `i` is more clear to me
- Similarly, `val` could be anything; calling it `character` instead is clearer

**Use a `while` loop.** Instead of creating a function within a function that  recursively calls itself while a condition is true, use a [`while` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while)—it's what its built for.

**Don't chain `return` statements.** Rather than nesting the output of the function within the internal recursive function, just wait until after the `while` loop is done updating the `amount` variable to output your result. This removes the need to conditionally check if the loop index matches the string length.

**Handle upper and lowercase results.** As previously written, your function would tell you there's only one T in "Tuxedo on a goat" even though there's two—one uppercase and one lowercase. Convert your function inputs to lowercase strings in order to handle this case.

**Use a strict equals (`===`) when possible.** In the conditional where you're checking if there's only one matching letter in the string, use a [strict equals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Strict_equality). You're checking if `amount` is `1`, not if `amount` is `1` or any truthy value.

```js
function getAmountOf(letter, string) {
  let lowercaseLetter = letter.toLowerCase()
  let lowercaseString = string.toLowerCase()
  let i = 0
  let amount = 0
  while (i <= string.length) {
    i += 1
    let character = lowercaseString[i]
    if (character === lowercaseLetter) {
      amount += 1
    }
  }
  if (amount === 1) {
    return `There's ${amount} ${letter} in "${string}"`
  } else {
    return `There's ${amount} ${letter}'s in "${string}"`
  }
}
console.log(getAmountOf('a', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
```

An alternative approach could be to use the [`.split()` method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) to break the input string into an array of substrings, and then return one less than the length of that array:

```js
function getAmountOf(letter, string) {
  let amount = string.toLowerCase().split(letter.toLowerCase()).length - 1
  return `There's ${amount} ${letter}${amount === 1 ? '' : `'s`} in "${string}"`
}
console.log(getAmountOf('a', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is complicated.

---

First, I simplified your code to distill the essence of the problem.

```
function getAmountOf(letter, string) {
    let amount = 0;
    for (const char of string) {
        if (char === letter) { amount++; }
    }
    const plural = (amount !== 1) ? "'s" : "";
    return `There's ${amount} ${letter}${plural} in ${string}`; 
}
```

Second, I refined the code to account for special cases: a single letter, upper to lower case, and Unicode code points (UTF-16 surrogate pairs).

```
function getAmountOf(letter, string) {
    let amount = 0;
    const cpLetter = letter.toLowerCase().codePointAt(0)
    const oneLetter = String.fromCodePoint(cpLetter)
    const lcString = string.toLowerCase()
    for (const char of lcString) {
        if (char.codePointAt(0) === cpLetter) { amount++; }
    }
    const plural = (amount !== 1) ? "'s" : "";
    return `There's ${amount} ${oneLetter}${plural} in ${string}`; 
}
```

Then, I ran some basic tests.

```
console.log(getAmountOf('a', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
console.log(getAmountOf('x', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
console.log(getAmountOf('U', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
console.log(getAmountOf('z', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));
console.log(getAmountOf('ax', 'Tuxedo on a goat.'));

$ node xamount.js
There's 2 a's in Tuxedo on a goat.
There's 1 x in Tuxedo on a goat.
There's 1 u in Tuxedo on a goat.
There's 0 z's in Tuxedo on a goat.
There's 2 a's in Tuxedo on a goat.
$
```

Comment: This is more of an alternative solution and not a review.

Comment: @RoToRa: It's a standard code review as practiced at Google and elsewhere. It identifies three problems. The first problem is complexity, the second problem is missing function, and the third problem is missing tests. The review includes suggestions on how to fix these problems. At Google, "Reviewers can propose alternatives, but only if they improve comprehension (by being less complex, for example) or functionality (by being more efficient, for example)." - Software Engineering at Google.

Comment: I concur with @RoToRa—this is an alternative solution and not a review as described in the [How to Answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) help article. Other organizations' code review practices are irrelevant to this forum; only the guidelines in the Help Center matter.